# Sum of Numbers C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, sum

I am supposed to write a program that asks the user for a positive integer value. The program should use a loop to get the sum of 
all the integers from 1 up to the number entered. For example, if the user enters 50, the loop will find the sum of 
1, 2, 3, 4, ... 50.

But for some reason it is not working, i am having trouble with my for loops but this is what i have down so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int positiveInteger;
    int startingNumber = 1;
    int i = 0;

    cout << "Please input an integer up to 100." << endl;

    cin >> positiveInteger;

    for (int i=0; i < positiveInteger; i++)
    {
        i = startingNumber + 1;
        cout << i;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I am just at a loss right now why it isn't working properly.

Comment: what do you think the `i = startingNumber +1;` part is for?

Comment: just a hint: keep an eye on your variables: startingNumber is used twice, once in the declaration for being 1, and a second time where you add 1 (..so 'i' will always be set to 2!)

Comment: I used `sum` to add the `i + 1` but it just prints the numbers i want to add all these numbers that it prints and that is where i am at loss.

Comment: You have to add `sum` each time to `sum` as well.

Comment: Yeah i tried that do i just put `sum + sum;` and then print it out?

Comment: I stll cant get them to add to the total...

Comment: `sum = sum + i`. The shorthand for it is `sum += i`

Comment: Yeah i put that right after `sum = i + 1;` but i still dont get the correct addition..

Comment: `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int positiveInteger;
int startingNumber = 1;

cout << "Please input an interger upto 100." << endl;

cin >> positiveInteger;

int sum = 0;
int total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < positiveInteger; i++)
 {
  sum = i + 1;
  sum = sum + i;
  cout << sum << " " << endl;
 }

 return 0;

}`

Comment: You're overwriting the value of sum when you do `sum = i+1`. Just put `sum = sum + i` in the loop and print it.

Comment: It doesnt print out the correct term for 5 for example 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15 but i get 10...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int positiveInteger;
    int startingNumber = 1;

    cout << "Please input an integer upto 100." << endl;

    cin >> positiveInteger;

    int result = 0;
    for (int i=startingNumber; i <= positiveInteger; i++)
    {
        result += i;
        cout << result;
    }

    cout << result;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Giving the answer away to obvious homework problems is ultimately not helpful to the poster; try to help them learn next time.

Comment: In the future, when giving help for homework try to _guide_ the OP to the answer instead of providing it outright.

Comment: This works perfect at least i was able to see what i did wrong now. Thanks! Although the answer was given haha.

Answer (score 11):

The loop is great; it's what's inside the loop that's wrong. You need a variable named `sum`, and at each step, add `i+1` to `sum`. At the end of the loop, `sum` will have the right value, so print it.

Answer (score 3):

I have the following formula that works without loops.  I discovered it while trying to find a formula for factorials:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned int positiveInteger;
    cout << "Please input an integer up to 100." << endl;
    cin >> positiveInteger;

    cout << (positiveInteger * (positiveInteger + 1)) / 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
int sum = startingNumber; 
for (int i=0; i < positiveInteger; i++) {     
    sum += i;
}
cout << sum;
```

But much easier is to note that the sum `1+2+...+n = n*(n+1) / 2`, so you do not need a loop at all, just use the formula `n*(n+1)/2`.

Answer (score 0):

mystycs, you are using the variable `i` to control your loop, **however** you are editing the value of `i` within the loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < positiveInteger; i++)
{
    i = startingNumber + 1;
    cout << i;
}
```

Try this instead:

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i=0; i < positiveInteger; i++)
{
    sum = sum + i;
    cout << sum << " " << i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int result = 0;


 for (int i=0; i < positiveInteger; i++)
    {
        result = startingNumber + 1;
        cout << result;
    }
```

Comment: That should be `result += startingNumber + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have *two* variables of the same name `i`. This calls for confusion.

Second, you should declare a variable called `sum`, which is initially zero. Then, in a loop, you should add to it the numbers from 1 upto and including `positiveInteger`. After that, you should output the `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

You are just updating the value of `i` in the loop. The value of `i` should also be added each time.

It is never a good idea to update the value of `i` inside the `for` loop. The `for` loop index should only be used as a counter. In your case, changing the value of `i` inside the loop will cause all sorts of confusion.

Create variable `total` that holds the sum of the numbers up to `i`.

So

```
 for (int i = 0; i < positiveInteger; i++)
        total += i;
```