# How to check whether a webpage contains a code sample or plain text?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

For example - [This_WebPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463507/sum-of-numbers-c) contains below code sample: [image]

How to check whether such code sample is present in a webpage or not?

Comment: It will be difficult to find a solution that works in the general case.  Looking for parts enclosed in `<code>` tags is a good first step.

Comment: Yes. <code> tag is working fine. But failing in the cases of forum pages such as : https://forums.asp.net/t/1742821.aspx?Javascript+not+running+properly. I was planning to use <pre> tag in such cases. Will that be good idea? I am afraid <pre> tag will output some false positive cases?

Comment: There is no easy reliable way.  You will have to set up a machine-learning infrastructure and create a dataset to train it manually for best results, and even then there will be false positives and negatives.  If you are not willing to put in that much effort, you are going to have to live with lower detection quality.

Answer (score 1):

Although I would also go with code/pre/source HTML tags, you can also analyze the content. For example, you could get a huge text corpus where you know it is only plain text (English wikipedia, but pre processed to filter code tags) as well as a huge code base (e.g. Linux kernel for C - I don't know what you need). With that, you could build a native Bayes classifier on word level.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/html.parser.html?highlight=html.parse#module-html.parser) to parse the html and care for ,  tags etc. A long time ago I needed to do the same and used [this](http://pastebin.com/E20CgL3X) snippet as reference to build my parser along with the documentation to extract code from an SO dump.

Machine learning classification is one way to go, another one would be, especially in the case you're mining for one or two specific languages, the Abstract Syntax Tree way. You could get your parsed results through an [AST extractor](https://github.com/thdiaman/ASTExtractor) (this one is a random one I used, there are plenty more) and see if it produces anything valid (ie if it's remotely like compilable code) or not.

Answer (score 0):

you could check for the existence of a `<pre>` element. This is used for pre-rendered content and is often used as a container for code examples (so that it will not run/be rendered in the browser)

Comment: If anything, the `<code>` tag should be checked for.